# Canonical does not provide updates for VLC media player?

Tags: vlc

I am trying to update VLC media player to the latest version, I've tried the usual apt-get update and upgrade, however it won't update to the latest version (2.2). My current version is below.

```
$ vlc --version
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
```

In the Ubuntu software centre, if I look at the details of VLC is just says,

```
"vCanonical does not provide updates for VLC media player. Some updates may be provided by the Ubuntu community."
```

I have tried installing the repository below and had no luck.

```
ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

I was asked to provide the output below for troubleshooting:

```
$ apt-cache policy vlc
vlc:
  Installed: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.4+git20150226+r54594+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck" with installing vlc from ppa? And what is Ubuntu version?

Comment: In Ubuntu 15.04 VLC is already 2.2.0.

Comment: And you have a weird "gea01d28" version. Where did you install it from? Please give output of `apt-cache policy vlc`.

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: And you have 14.04 version of Ubuntu ))) Trusty is 14.04.

Comment: No I don't! How do i check?

Comment: `cat /etc/lsb-release`

Comment: Well apparently I do then lol. I could have sworn I was on 15.04

Comment: So use my answer to install VLC for 14.04.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Quick question, how come different Ubuntu versions need different ppa's? I've not come across this situation before and I thought ppa packages were repositories that could be used on the latest releases, stable and experimental?

Comment: It depends on ppa maintainers what versions for which releases to place there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu 14.04 you can install VLC 2.2.1 using [this](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media/) ppa.

Run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

In Ubuntu 15.04 VLC is already version 2.2.0.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 15 can I still use this?

Comment: No. This is only for 14.04. You can install it from ppa:videolan/stable-daily @johnsmith

Comment: I already tried this. I installed that ppa (the stable-daily ppa) then did a apt-get update and upgrade. No success.

Comment: What is "no success"? What does terminal show?

Comment: I can't copy paste all the output, but briefly: I install the ppa with no issues, then do a sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade and it doesn't see that there is an update. So a version check afterwards shows it's still on 2.1.6.

Comment: You must have installed vlc from some ppa and locked version.

Comment: @Pilot6, I have to agree with him. No errors to report. It says VLC is already in the latest version. I see your latest comment now. So a uninstall and reinstall might fix?